# Input leap with Android

Tags: android, linux, input-devices

I'm looking for software to [input leap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Input_Leap) my mouse (and keyboard, but not a priority) from my PC (GNU/Linux) to my Android device. I used to use [barrier](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier) when I needed to link to a Mac instead of Android, unfortunately, it does not work with Android.

What I've tried so far is Deskdock which worked just as expected but had lots of bugs and it does not seem to be maintained any longer.

I can use [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) to connect to the device, but I want to leap my mouse there instead. I.e. treat it as it was another monitor that the mouse can access.